# Parallax Effect

Tags: css, parallax

As I understand from the formal definition, parallax effect happens when some images move at a different speed than the others thus creating the illusion that the slower moving ones are relatively behind the faster ones. And there are these kind of webpages where the background moves at a faster pace than the content. But I see that pages with background images having `background-position:fixed` are also given as examples of the parallax effect. (e.g. http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp) Is this a misconception in terms of the definition of parallax?

Comment: First of all, W3Schools are a horrible place to get information. It's not an authoritative resource (even though it tries to masquerade as one). And yes, using position:fixed is a very edge case of parallax effect. It can still be technically called parallax as the foreground and background elements are moving at different speeds—like how the constellations remain still when we travel in the night.

Comment: w3schools is a misconception of a learning resource. And you're right just out of your sane common sense. What they show as *parallax* is **no Parallax** at all (to some infinitesime extent). We all know what parallax is - and that surely isn't a fixed background image.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan You've taken the words out of my mouth.  The introduction on that page says "different speed" but it only tells you how to do zero speed.  W3Schools has mostly seemed to me to be a good resource, but this sticks out like a sore thumb.

Answer (score 0):

Parallax is a word that comes from the sciences that means ["a displacement or difference in the apparent position of an object viewed along two different lines of sight, and is measured by the angle or semi-angle of inclination between those two lines."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallax) Often when you're measuring volumes of liquid in beakers, you record the volumes as every individual viewing them sees them (because of their individual parralax) and take the average of them to record in a scientific experiment.

The effect of parallax is often used on the web to create the illusion of depth. One of my favourite examples of this is [www.jessandruss.us](http://jessandruss.us/). There are MANY ways to achieve the effect of parallax on the web, and using fixed positioning can be one way of doing that :)